# OSMdroid change TileSource at Runtime

Tags: android, tiles, osmdroid, openstreetmap

i working with osmdroid and i want to change the TileSource at runtime (via menu entry). For example i can change between OSM TileSource and GoogleTileSource.

Problem: Everything works fine, but when i change the TileSource while the mapview is loading a Tile in the background, it changes the TileSource but one or two tiles are from the TileSource befor. So i see a mixed MapView with OSMTiles and one or two GoogleTiles.

The tileCache is cleared everytime after changing the TileSource. But the loading tile in the background isnt in the cache at this moment, so he put this tile to the cache, after clearing it.

Any Idea to workaround this issue?? It is all based on osmdroid, i only work with `setTileSource(ITileSource)`

Thanks and Greetz

Comment: Where do you get the Google tiles from? I don't see that as an option within the TileSourceFactory's constants.

Comment: @NickT: i guess he is switching mapview activity (and not tilesource)

Comment: no no i switch only TileSources and created my oun TileSource for Google ;-)

Comment: An interesting aproach, the issue is the no cacheing caluse in the google licence.  I have a frame with a google and an Osmroid view in it.

Comment: i read something in a tutorial, that it is not allowed to use google maps offline. But he told it is allowed to cache, so he cached the tiles for some years :) http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html

Comment: @Mirko: If you plan on releasing an app using Google tiles, I'd get some good legal advice first. I'd hate you to be sued by Google. Personally I think that if the tiles were created using Mobac 1.8, then it's a breach of the licence, but then I'm not a lawyer

Comment: @NickT dont worry, i know about this problem and i only put the google  tiles to this app to test if it is possible. If i need the google maps, i will use googles mapView! But thank you for the advice.

Comment: I had a similar issue but was because I made the silly mistake of passing the same (non-unique) 'name' for the constructor of my OnlineTileSourceBase / ITileSource subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a proper bug to me.  I think you should report it as such.  I can not see anything like it in the [issues](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/list) list.  It looks like the bad tile even gets into the wrong cache on the sd card which is bad as it will be there for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using osmdroid3.0.6.jar (and I think you are, as I can reproduce this bug if I build with 3.0.6). I think it's another manifestation of the issue I raised [osmdroid-android-3.0.6.jar, tile loading slow or fails](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=289&sort=-id). This bug has been accepted by the authors.

I suggest you go back to using the 3.0.5 jar. I don't get any problems with that. (I'm still puzzled as to how you get to use Google tiles with Osmdroid)

Comment: thanks, i also think it is a bug. (For google tiles you only need this page http://mt3.google.com/vt/v=w2.97&x=74327&y=50500&z=17 and create your oun TileSource for osmdroid)

Comment: I think this is a different issue I just went back to 3.0.5 in my app and saw the same effect.

Comment: in my case it isnt slow as well. I looked into the src of osmdroid. In the method setTileSource() it cleares the cache but it do not stop the current download or something. So the cache is clean but the download is loading and when it is finished it puts the tile to the cache. So it is possible that he puts 1 or 2 of the old TileSource tiles into the cache and then the new tiles. I found a workarround but isnt really nice i will put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think we all think it is a bug (or maybe it is not wanted to switch the TileSource at runtime).

I created a little Workarround. It works but it is not realy nice or recommended.

I created a new mapView and extend the osm MapView. Than create a RequestCompleteHandler, so i can see when a tile is finish loading and saved into the cache. Than i count every cached tile and only allow to switch the tileSource after 15 tiles are loaded. (at the start of the app osmdroid will load 15 tiles and only load some more after moving the map)

```
class RequestCompleteHandler extends SimpleInvalidationHandler{
    private LbsMapView mMapView;

    public RequestCompleteHandler(LbsMapView pView) {
        super(pView);
        mMapView = pView;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
        super.dispatchMessage(msg);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "HANDLER HAT GERUFEN! BACKE BACKE KUCHEN!! " + tileCount);
        tileCount++;
    }

}
```

then override the setTileSource method:

```
@Override
public void setTileSource(ITileSource aTileSource) {
    if(tileCount <= 15){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Jetz eher nich", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        tileCount = 0;
        super.setTileSource(aTileSource);
    }

}
```

and you need to set and initialise the Handler in the constructor:

```
mHandler = new RequestCompleteHandler(this);
    getTileProvider().setTileRequestCompleteHandler(mHandler);
```

done. Now you can switch the tileSource only when it allready loads 15 tiles. 
A little Problem: if the source are not working and do not load any tile you are in problems :D

But important: it is not recommended, its realy ugly code

Comment: Are you sure it's always going to be 15 tiles.  I thought the cache started as 9 and then grew to 16, at least that's what I see in the logcat in my case.

Comment: i am not 100% sure, i only counted 15 after starting the app without moving the map. But if you move the map and switch the TileSource it also happens that the tiles are mixed. But the user need to be fast.

Comment: I post that as an issue for osmdroid... they need to clear the download queue after you use setTileSource so i think we need to wait for an new version :)

Comment: I'm hitting the exact same problem. Was an issue logged for this? If so, can you post a link?